# Avoiding undefined behaviour: passing a temporary to a `std::function` which has a const ref member variable

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

The following example is a simplified version found in production code

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    std::string myString = "World";
};

struct B
{
    void operator()() 
    {
        std::cout << a.myString;
    }
    const A& a;
};

std::vector<std::function<void()>> v;

void Store(std::function<void()> myFunc)
{
    v.emplace_back(myFunc);
}

void Print()
{
    v[0]();
}

int main()
{
    A a; a.myString = "Hello";

    Store(B{a}); // temporary passed with a const-ref of on-the-stack `A`
    Print();
}
```

In production code, accessing the string `A` (i.e. invoking the function through the `vector` which in turn accesses `myString` in `A`) results in a crash. Compiler Explorer seems to be okay with it, however if this behaviour is undefined, the output probably cannot be trusted: https://godbolt.org/z/cPPKeK9zd

Assuming this is undefined behaviour and I can only store a `const &` to `A`, what can I do in the `Store(...)` function to issue a compiler error and try to catch the undefined behaviour at compile time.

Comment: Why would this be UB? `a` is still alive when it's value is printed.

Comment: @super `a` is alive, but the `B` object that refers to `a` is not alive anymore, so the reference to `a` is not reliable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't understand the reasoning. There is a copy of the `B` object wrapped in a `std::function` that still refers to the same `a`. What does that have to do with being reliable?

Comment: @Samaursa do you have the same problem if you change `Store()` to use `v.emplace_back(std::move(myFunc));`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau that will take a while to test, as I will have to make the change and fire off a custom build in the pipeline. But, I will try nevertheless.
@super the code does result in a crash, and if I force the storage of `A` as a copy instead of a `const &` (by changing some code locally for `A` for testing and firing off a build), then I do not get a crash. If it's not undefined behaviour, great, but I wanted to confirm. Judging by Remy's reply and upvotes to his comment, it seems that it's not completely obvious.

Comment: @super What do you think causes the `operator())(`) from `B` to suddenly use some other reference than the one in the temporary?

Comment: It uses a copy of that reference in the temporary, but the `A` object is still alive, so that reference is valid, and the `B` object which is temporary is not itself referenced.

Comment: @Samaursa Judging by your comments, it sounds like the example you've produced here fails to replicate the problem you're experiencing in production. Are you able to turn this into a _reproducible_ example? Otherwise it could really be anyone's guess what the problem is. From inspection, there are no problems, as `std::function` stores a copy of `B` internally, which holds onto a valid `A` reference. Is your production environment doing anything different? Could it be that the `A` reference goes out-of-scope in your real code, or some other UB is corrupting data and only failing here?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If I had to guess it would be that in the real code, there is an issue with copying `B` for some reason. Too little information to make any accurate guesses though IMO.

Comment: I double checked everything and that is a correct reproduction.

`B` in production code is a struct with an overloaded operator `operator()(...)` and an explicit constructor that takes `A` by `const &` and stores it in it's member variable `a`. The original `A` does _not_ go out of scope.

Since everyone is agreeing that it's not UB, at least I can focus on some other potential cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example has no undefined behavior.

Calling `Store` copy-initializes the argument of type `std::function<void()>` from the temporary object of type `B`. In doing so, `std::function` uses perfect forwarding to initialize its own internal object of type `B`, which is therefore move-constructed from the original temporary.

The call to `emplace_back` copy-constructs the function which therefore copy-constructs the internal object of type `B`.

That the initial `B` object is a temporary is irrelevant, as the copy inside the function inside the vector is not. The reference to `A` inside this `B` copy still points to the same `A` object, which is still within its lifetime.